# Hydro-Bromination Product 1,4-Benzoquinone

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

What will the products on addition reaction of 1,4-benzoquinone with HBr ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the mechanistic approach :
[image: the full step by step mechanism:]

Comment: The Dissociation of HBr into H+ and Br- is implicit!

Comment: Thus final product is ortho bromo, 1,4 diphenol

Comment: Why don't you add the info in your comments to your question? And, do you have a better image, please? This one hurts eyes.

Comment: I agree, the picture is barely readable, your comments also belong into the post. Just [edit] it. The post was flagged low-quality because of these issues. For now I am not voting to delete, but these kinds of posts should not be the standard.

Comment: I apologize, the last twonsteps are tautomerism to give enol form which is aromatic, hence stable!